# Visualising a quadratic relationship from a linear model using predictorEffects

Tags: r

I seek to visualise the quadratic (rather than linear) relationship for the following simple linear model:

```r
Top_model <- lm(Response~Predictor^2,data=data)
```

I also seek to visualise the residuals and confidence intervals for this quadratic relationship. Can anyone please help with suggestions for code that will allow me to do this in predictorEffects? The following code results in a linear representation of the model, however I seek a quadratic one. Do I need to somehow transform the x axis?

```r
plot(predictorEffects(Top_model, ~ Predictor))
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `poly()` to fit your model in a non-linear way:

```r
Top_model <- lm(Response ~ poly(Predictor,2), data=data)
```

It's also possible to expand the model for example by

```r
Another_Model <- lm(Response ~ poly(Predictor_1,2) * poly(Predictor_2,2), data=data)
```

which gives you all combinations of `Predicator_1` and `Predictor_2`, i.e.

```r
Predictor_1
Predictor_1^2

Predictor_2
Predictor_2^2

Predictor_1 * Predictor_2
Predictor_1^2 * Predictor_2
Predictor_1 * Predictor_2^2
Predictor_1^2 * Predictor_2^2
```

Comment: Thankyou. Your suggestion worked perfectly. The following code produces the model and visualisation: Top_model<-lm(Response~poly(Predictor,2),data=data)
plot(predictorEffects(Top_model, residuals=TRUE),partial.residuals=list(smooth=TRUE,span=0.75,lty="dashed"),main="",xlab="Predictor",ylab="Response")